# Toad SQL Data Import - Flat File - Carriage Return in Middle of String Field

Tags: sql, csv, import, toad, carriage-return

How do I import a CSV file where there is a carriage return in the middle of one string (quoted) field?

For example, suppose this is my CSV file with 3 records, where the column names are included:

```
FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3, FieldName4
"DataA1
",DataA2,"DataA3",DataA4
"DataB1
",DataB2,"DataB3",DataB4
"DataC1
",DataC2,"DataC3",DataC4
```

My data always puts a newline before the end quote for the first column in the data.

Comment: Is double quotation mark part of the column value?

Comment: Yes, the first column (FieldName1) always has a carriage return in the middle of the data for each record.